# Can I patent an old piece of hardware?

Tags: old, door, handle, cast, iron

I have found a door handle that must be at least 100 years old. It is made of cast iron. There are no marks on it.

I would assume this item is no longer patented, but if it were, how would I be able to verify it?

I would like to patent or copyright it and manufacture it for sale myself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about how to find if a product is patented in the general sense. But as a practical manner, if the hardware is 100+ years old, it is certainly not patented now (even if it was in the past). Patents generally last for no more than 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Q. Can I patent an old piece of hardware?

A. No.  The public (via the government) grants patents in return for a description of how to do something new, not something that has been known for 100 years.